# Ayuda por favor con sentencia SQL

Tags: mysql, oracle, sql, group-by

Tengo dos tablas en oracle, una es de vehículo y otra es de mantenimientos, esta última tiene un campo de fecha y una llave foránea que la relaciona con la tabla vehículo mediante el id. Lo que necesito es consultar los vehículos que aparecen en mantenimiento al menos una vez en cada fecha de un rango de fecha. Me explico, si, por ejemplo, ingreso un rango de fecha 2017-03-06 y 2017-03-09 se traen los vehículos que tuvieron mantenimiento los días 6, 7, 8 y 9. Si al menos uno de esos días no tiene registro en mantenimiento (ejemplo: 6, 8 y 9) no debe ser tomado en cuenta.
Gracias de antemano por sus respuestas
Agrego una imagen para aclarar un poco mas mi requerimiento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrego el SQLde la base de datos:

```
CREATE TABLE vehiculo(
    vehi_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    vehi_matricula VARCHAR(10)
);
CREATE TABLE mantenimiento(
    mant_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    vehi_id INT,
    mant_fecha DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY(vehi_id) REFERENCES vehiculo(vehi_id)
);

INSERT INTO vehiculo values(1,'ABC');
INSERT INTO vehiculo values(2,'DEF');
INSERT INTO vehiculo values(3,'GHI');
INSERT INTO vehiculo values(4,'JKL');

INSERT INTO mantenimiento values(1,1, DATE '2017-03-06');
INSERT INTO mantenimiento values(2,2, DATE '2017-03-06');
INSERT INTO mantenimiento values(3,3, DATE '2017-03-06');
INSERT INTO mantenimiento values(4,4, DATE '2017-03-06');

INSERT INTO mantenimiento values(5,1, DATE '2017-03-07');
INSERT INTO mantenimiento values(6,3, DATE '2017-03-07');
INSERT INTO mantenimiento values(7,4, DATE '2017-03-07');

INSERT INTO mantenimiento values(8,1, DATE '2017-03-08');
INSERT INTO mantenimiento values(9,2, DATE '2017-03-08');
INSERT INTO mantenimiento values(10,3, DATE '2017-03-08');
INSERT INTO mantenimiento values(11,4, DATE '2017-03-08');
INSERT INTO mantenimiento values(12,4, DATE '2017-03-08');

INSERT INTO mantenimiento values(13,1, DATE '2017-03-09');
INSERT INTO mantenimiento values(14,2, DATE '2017-03-09');
INSERT INTO mantenimiento values(15,3, DATE '2017-03-09');
```

y las sentencia usada sin éxito:

```
SELECT distinct v.vehi_id, v.vehi_matricula
FROM vehiculo v         
JOIN mantenimiento m    
ON v.vehi_id=m.vehi_id    
WHERE m.mant_fecha 
BETWEEN TO_DATE('2017-03-06', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
AND TO_DATE('2017-03-09', 'YYYY-MM-DD') ;
```

La anterior me retorna todas las matriculas puesto que todas tienen un mantenimiento en el rango de fechas y solo necesito las que han tenido al menos un mantenimiento en cada día del rango de fechas

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a S.O. en español. Te invito a leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, puedes hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y así ganarás tu primera medalla. En cuanto a tu pregunta, ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Cómo se llaman tus tablas? ¿Podrías postear el DDL de las mismas? Saludos

Comment: ¿Sería posible que nos pasaras esa base de datos en SQL además de las consultas que has intentado tú para llegar a la solución?

Comment: Saludos, gracias por sus respuestas, he agregado el SQL para creación de la base de datos y una imagen explicando un poco mejor el requerimiento.
Me disculpo por no poner el código en formato definido por la plataforma pero no logré que se visualizara correctamente

Comment: Recuerda votar y validar la respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente estamos ante una división y, como en Oracle la tienes, podrías dividir mantenimientos entre fechas y tendrías el resultado. Te doy la solución compatible con MySQL y aquellos sistemas que no tengan implementada esta operación para que la respuesta quede más versátil y podamos incluir la etiqueta mysql también.

En primer lugar, necesitas crear un tabla en la que figuren las fechas en las que se han realizado mantenimientos. Como comentas que ha habido dos vehículos que los han realizado todos, pues las obtengo de ahí.

```
CREATE TABLE fechas
  SELECT DISTINCT mant_fecha
    FROM mantenimiento ORDER BY mant_fecha;
```

En un caso real esto no sería válido y tendrías que generarla tú con un calendario de revisiones en la mano, porque no tendrías garantía de que hubiera un vehículo que las hubiera realizado todas.

Ahora tienes que hacer un paso intermedio y sacar aquellas revisiones que se hayan hecho el mismo día que la que vas a tener en cuenta para tu análisis. Es una simple proyección:

```
SELECT DISTINCT vehi_id,mant_fecha FROM mantenimiento;
```

Y ahora llega la parte interesante: contar cuántos días ha visitado el taller cada vehículo en ese rango de fechas y quedarnos con aquellos vehículos que hayan ido TODOS los días (y aquí tendrías la famosa división, en MySQL, como no la tiene, tenemos que hacerla a mano con un HAVING)

```
SELECT vehi_id FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT vehi_id,mant_fecha FROM mantenimiento
  ) dias GROUP BY vehi_id HAVING COUNT(*)=(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fechas WHERE mant_fecha
      BETWEEN '2017-03-06' AND '2017-03-09'  
  );
```

Y ya sólo te queda combinar con vehículos para obtener las matrículas:

```
SELECT v.vehi_id,vehi_matricula FROM (
    SELECT vehi_id FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT vehi_id,mant_fecha FROM mantenimiento
      ) dias GROUP BY vehi_id HAVING COUNT(*)=(
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fechas WHERE mant_fecha
          BETWEEN '2017-03-06' AND '2017-03-09'  
      )  
  ) mantenimiento_completo JOIN vehiculo v
  ON mantenimiento_completo.vehi_id=v.vehi_id;
```

Comment: Excelente, mil gracias, es justo lo que requería para solucionar este requerimiento. Agradezco mucho su tiempo.

Comment: Un placer, una división no se encuentra todos los días :) Recuerda votar y aceptar la respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Una manera podría ser contar las fechas de mantenimiento distintas de cada vehículo en el rango solicitadosy si coincide con la cantidad de días dentro de dicho rango, se cumpliría la condición que pides: *los vehículos que aparecen en mantenimiento al menos una vez en cada fecha de un rango de fecha*

```
SELECT *
         FROM vehiculo V
         INNER JOIN (SELECT vehi_id, 
                            COUNT(DISTINCT mant_fecha) AS Dias
                            FROM mantenimiento
                            WHERE mant_fecha >= TO_DATE('2017-03-06', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                                  AND mant_fecha <= TO_DATE('2017-03-09', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                            GROUP BY vehi_id
                     ) M
                     ON M.vehi_id = V.vehi_id
         WHERE M.Dias = (TO_DATE('2017-03-09', 'YYYY-MM-DD') - TO_DATE('2017-03-06', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) + 1
```

Mediante una subconsulta "contamos" los días distintos de mantenimiento para cada vehículo, luego simplemente filtramos aquellos dónde este número sea igual a la cantidad de días del rango.

Comment: Hola Patricio, qué bien que tengamos diferentes soluciones, ¿y si hubiera algún festivo en ese rango de fechas en el que no fuera necesario realizar el mantenimiento? :) Propuse la tabla fechas por hacer el problema más realista...

Answer (score -1):

Segun como esta la estructura de tablas podes hacer el query. Es bastante simple. Adiciona aca la estructura.

Si el campo fecha esta como DATE o TIMESTAMP cambia la forma de extraer el dia de la fecha, pues TIMESTAMP va a limitar por horario tambien. Si no podes pasar TIMESTAMP a fecha sin horario, pero es menos performante.

Un ejemplo con DATE mas o menos seria:

```
SELECT v.id, v.modelo, v.marca 
FROM vehiculo v          -- PODES DIRECTAMENTE ESCRIBIR LO SIGUIENTE SI TENES LAS CLAVES
JOIN mantenimiento m     -- (PK Y FK / PRIMARY KEY Y FOREIGN KEY) CREADAS
ON v.id=m.vehiculo_id    -- FROM vehiculo v, mantenimiento m
WHERE m.fecha 
BETWEEN TO_DATE('2017-MAR-06', 'YYYY-MON-DD')
AND TO_DATE('2017-MAR-09', 'YYYY-MON-DD') ;
```

Con TIMESTAMP seria asi:

```
SELECT v.id, v.modelo, v.marca 
FROM vehiculo v, mantenimiento m
WHERE m.fecha 
BETWEEN TO_DATE('2017-MAR-06', 'YYYY-MON-DD')
AND TO_DATE('2017-MAR-09', 'YYYY-MON-DD') + 1 ;
```

Comment: Saludos y primero que nada gracias por tu respuesta, he intentado una consulta similar a la que planteaste pero no es lo que requiero.
Supongamos:

Tengo 3 vehículos con id 1, 2 y 3 y a su vez tengo registros de los mantenimientos realizados a esos vehículos.

El vehículo de id 1 tiene registro de mantenimientos los días 6, 7, 8 y 9(se reporta)

El vehículo de id 2 solo tiene registro de mantenimientos los días 6, 7 y 8 ( No se reporta)

El vehículo de id 3 tiene 2 registros de mantenimientos el día 6, un registro el 8 y uno el 9, pero no tiene mantenimientos el día 7 (No se reporta)

Comment: Buena aportación: si el campo fecha hubiera sido de tipo DATETIME habría que haber hecho esa conversión para poder formar los grupos. De ahí que sea tan importante aportar el código SQL para formular la pregunta.

Comment: @David Pero no es necesario, pues ya el 'YYYY-MON-DD' especifica la parte que se necesita.

Comment: @Dev117 no entiendo tu comentario, por favor indica la estructura de tablas, y los tipos de cada columna.

Comment: No es necesario utilizar TO_DATE para quitar la hora porque el campo es de tipo DATE, no DATETIME, así que no tiene hora

Comment: Ha modificado la pregunta para aportar la estructura de la base de datos en SQL

Comment: Me votan con un menos cuando no estaba el requerimiento bien expresado y solo quise aportar. Gracias.
Ademas la forma del query marcado como solucion es totalmente desprolijo. 
Estabas necesitanto la cantidad de veces, no los dias.
Deberias de usar particiones.